# Loading default data (such as a PageTitle)

Tags: xcode

I'm writing an app where I would like a lot of the data, literals, even image files, to be sourced from data file(s) rather than being hard coded.

So for example if I open a new page the Page Title would come from the file and overwrite what was typed in.

Is this possible and if so what's the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at resources files: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html